# Python readline() doesn't read line properly

Tags: python

When I have a text file and the first line is "hello", if I write

```
reader = open('txtfile.txt', 'r')
line = reader.readline()
print(line)
```

it will print "hello".
Then, when I write

```
input = input()
if line == input:
    print('they are the same')
else:
    print('they are not the same')
```

it says that they are not the same, even when the input is "hello".  Is this a problem with my code or does readline() not allow for this?

Comment: Are you sure there are no newlines? You also shouldn't overwrite the names of builtin functions like `input`.

Comment: there are newlines, the file goes something like
`hello`
`other words`
`more words`
does this affect the way it reads the file?

Comment: Try printing `len(line)` and comparing that with `len(input)` *but note you should change the name of the variable `input` so it doesn’t overwrite `input()`)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `with open() as.. :` [because](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)...

> This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.

Your program would become:

```
with open('txtfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        answer = input('\nContent?')
        if line.replace('\n','') == answer:
            print('they are the same')
        else:
            print('they are not the same')
```

Also, avoid naming your variable `'input'` since it will shadow the name of the build-in `input()`.

---

If your file is:

```
hello
Hi
bye
```

then your first line would be `'hello\n'`. `replace()` removes that `\n` before the comparison.